# Extracting hidden files out from an image using Java

Tags: java, cryptography, hidden-files

We can hide rar/zip files inside an image in following ways. This concept is known as Steganography.

Suppose I want to hide a rar file in an image , I will write this command in Windows command prompt

```
copy /b image.jpg+as.zip hidden.jpg
```

Now to get back the contents,we can use Winrar/7zip or any other utility to open the hidden.jpg and it will display all its contents

Now to read a zip file I am using this java code

```
try{
            File file=new File(name);
            ZipFile zipFile=new ZipFile(file);
            Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry>enumeration=zipFile.entries();

            System.out.println("Listing Entries in the zipfile");
            while(enumeration.hasMoreElements()){
                Object key=enumeration.nextElement();
                System.out.println(key.toString()+":"+zipFile.getEntry(key.toString()));
            }

            zipFile.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
```

This code works fine for normal zip file/But when I try to open the "hidden.jpg" file with this code it is causing error. I tested the same with Apache Common Compress Library also . Can anybody point some way how I can do this in Java ?

I am sure this can be done cause we can view the hidden files using tools like WinRar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not real steganography since you are not hiding anything in the image. You are only adding data in the end of the file and if the image is edited in any way, the additional data is lost.

The only reason some (not all) archivers can find the "hidden" data is because they search the whole file for a possible archive. Normal library routines do not. They expect the archive to start in the beginning.

So if you want to open the archive, you have to find the start position. This may be possible by opening the image file and determining its size, or just searching for the beginning of the archive yourself.

But as I said, this is not steganography and nothing is hidden in the image.

Also, *stenography* is writing quick hand, *steganography* is hiding data inside another.

Comment: Steganography is about hiding data in a concealed manner, so that someone doesn't know anything is hidden to begin with. Appending data at the end of a file is still considered steganography, even if it won't fool some of the more experienced ones. There are also many steganographic algorithms where if the carrier file is edited and/or resaved the hidden data can suffer distortion. Pixel lsb substitution into saving the image to jpeg is a prime example. Still steganography, just not robust.